# Strings are being printing inside quotes

Tags: python, string, printing, quotes

Example:

```
>>> print "How do you do"
```

It prints as

```
'How do you do'
```

or

```
>>> x = "How do you do"
>>> print x
'How do you do'
```

I have just started learning python. All my print commands are coming in this way. What do I do?

Comment: Where are you typing these commands?  In a Windows Command Prompt, a Linux shell, an IDE?  It's odd that the built-in Python `print` command would display those quotes (as @jamylak's answer demonstrates).

Comment: I agree. Pics (screenshot) or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = "How do you do"
>>> x
'How do you do' # representation of x
>>> print x
How do you do # printed version of x
```

Comment: @user140767 Use `%s` instead